# Changing views on a window with a button click

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, nswindow, nsviewcontroller

what I'm basically trying to make is a very simple program that can switch back and forth between 2 views on a single window.

When the program loads there is a window with a custom view that contains a login button. When clicked, the view changes to a second custom view that contains a label and a logout button. I have this much working.

What I can't figure out is how to get the logout button to bring me back to the first view.

Here is the code for the AppDelegate class where i have the button method to switch the view:

header:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>

@property (weak) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSView *loginView;

- (IBAction)loginButtonClicked:(id)sender;

@end
```

implementation:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "myCustomView.h"


@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    // Insert code here to initialize your application
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    // Insert code here to tear down your application
}

- (IBAction)loginButtonClicked:(id)sender {
    [_loginView removeFromSuperview];
    myCustomView *new = [[myCustomView alloc]initWithNibName:@"myCustomView" bundle:nil];
    [[[self window]contentView]addSubview:[new view]];
}

@end
```

This is the code for my custom class that is a subclass of NSViewController.

header:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@class AppDelegate;

@interface myCustomView : NSViewController

@property (strong) IBOutlet NSView *logoutView;

- (IBAction)logoutButtonClicked:(id)sender;

@end
```

implementation:

```
#import "myCustomView.h"


@implementation myCustomView

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do view setup here.
}

- (IBAction)logoutButtonClicked:(id)sender {
    [_logoutView removeFromSuperview];
    myCustomView *newController = [[myCustomView alloc]initWithNibName:@"MainMenu" bundle:nil];
    [[[self window]contentView]addSubView:[newController view]];
    //this does not work. No visible @interface for 'myCustomClass' declares the selector 'window'
    }

@end
```

The button method to go back to the login page is where I'm stuck. Even though I've added the header file for `AppDelegate` into `myCustomClass` I cannot use the instance of NSWindow. What am I doing wrong here? Am I at least on the right track? any help here is greatly appreciated.

I also tried using `@class` instead of `#import`, but still can't use the instance of `NSWindow` from `AppDelegate`.

Here are the pictures of my two xib files:

[[image: AppDelegate.xib]][1

[image: myCustomView.xib]

UPDATE: The suggestions from Paul Patterson in his comments were very helpful, but haven't solved my problem. For now what I am doing to get my project to work is putting the buttons in the window instead of the views and then hiding them when i don't need them. This works and I can switch back and forth, however I still can't figure out how to use a button on a custom view itself to load a different view onto the same window.

Comment: Use at (at symbol) class in the header file to refer to those NSView objects.

Comment: I tried this, but it still will not let me use the instance of `NSWindow` from the `AppDelegate` class. Getting the same error.

Comment: I don't see it in your code.

Comment: Added what I tried into the code above.

Comment: You don't need NSViewController.  Use the class symbol to let AppDelegate access those two NSView objects, not the other way around.  So add two custom NSView objects to the middle pane of MainMenu.xib.

Comment: Swapping views in and out of a 'parent' view is a pretty common task, and Apple provide you with API specifically designed to allow you to do it. Have a look at the [``NSViewController``](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSViewController_Class/) class reference - in particular the section titled *'Managing Child View Controllers in a Custom Container'*; there's also a [sample app](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/ViewController/Introduction/Intro.html) that demos transitions from one view to another and back.

Comment: I realize this is much later, but for any who stumble upon this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ScB9ZJbkCJI&index=35&list=PLE83F832121568D36